# how can i make library with Vue.js (Feat. store, router)

Tags: javascript, vue.js

first, i'm sorry that my English is not good.
...

I want to make vue.js components module.
I tried simple button component module and It works(it include vuex).
I saw [this page](https://itnext.io/create-a-vue-js-component-library-part-2-c92a42af84e9).

and I want to make some module with 5 components that use both store and vue-router.
so I tried like this.

```
import LoadingSpinner from './components/common/LodingSpinner.vue';
import Modal from './components/common/Modal.vue';
import InputPage from './components/InputPage.vue';
import Page from './components/Page.vue';
import ProcessingPage from './components/ProcessingPage.vue';

import store from './store/index.js';
import route from './routes/index.js';

export default {
  install(Vue, options) {
    if (!options || !options.store) {
      throw new Error('Please initialise plugin with a Vuex store.')
    }

    options.store.registerModule('dummylib', store);
    options.route.registerModule('dummylib', route);

    Vue.component('loading-spinner', LoadingSpinner);
    Vue.component('modal', Modal);
    Vue.component('input-page', InputPage);
    Vue.component('page', Page);
    Vue.component('processing-page', ProcessingPage);
  }
```

when i finished it and install in new project, I can't see even App.vue and all components are missing.

Here is the main.js of the new project that will include the module.

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import store from './store';
import DummyButton from 'dummylib';
import router from './routes';

import InputPage from 'dummylib';
import Page from 'dummylib';
import ProcessingPage from 'dummylib';
import Modal from 'dummylib';
import LoadingSpinner from 'dummylib';

Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.use(DummyButton, {store});
Vue.use(InputPage, { store });
Vue.use(Page, { store });
Vue.use(ProcessingPage, { store });
Vue.use(Modal, { store });
Vue.use(LoadingSpinner);

new Vue({
  store,
  router,
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

how can i solve this problems...
thank you for watching my question with not good english.
i hope you understand my intension.

Comment: Do you see any errors when building your app? I see you are importing the default export of `dummylib` several times. Maybe you want to wrap the imported modules with curly braces. Ex: `import { DummyButton } from 'dummylib'`

Comment: @Chin.Udara thank you for answering! I apply that! thank you!

Comment: Did it solve your problem?

Comment: @Chin.Udara I asked to my senior engineer and He told me this way is not efficient way. He recomended to me to divide the functions into smaller pieces. so first, I tried divide component. when It done, I will make library with that components. :)